# How to Databind multiple Checkboxlist into a Gridview

Tags: for-loop, datagridview, checkboxlist

ERROR: Getting output table show some blank rows in each column after the first column.
This code works as, there is 4 checkboxlist each of it containing 4 list item. When selecting each of the list item it should be displayed in the
specified column .

Right Output: Each column with specified rows in the right position

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 fm = new Form2();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            
            dt.TableName = "FoodOrder";

            dt.Clear();
            dt.Columns.Add("WelcomeDrinks");
            dt.Columns.Add("Starter");
            dt.Columns.Add("MainMeals");
            dt.Columns.Add("Desserts");
                   
            for (int i = 0; i < chk1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (chk1.GetItemChecked(i))
                {

                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    row["WelcomeDrinks"] = (string)chk1.Items[i];
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);                                    
                }
            }
           
            for (int i = 0; i < chk2.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                              
                if (chk2.GetItemChecked(i))
                {
                    
                    DataRow workrow = dt.NewRow();                 
                    workrow["Starter"] = (string)chk2.Items[i];
                   dt.Rows.Add(workrow);                                      

                }
            }
           
            for (int i = 0; i < chk3.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (chk3.GetItemChecked(i))
                {
                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    row["MainMeals"] = (string)chk3.Items[i];
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }

           
            for (int i = 0; i < chk4.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (chk4.GetItemChecked(i))
                {             
                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    row["Desserts"] = (string)chk4.Items[i];
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }


            fm.Grid1.DataSource = dt;

            fm.Show();

        }
```

Comment: In each of the `for` loops, when the line of code… `dt.Rows.Add(WelcomeDrink);` or `dt.Rows.Add(Starter);` … executes, this will put the value `WelcomeDrink` and `Starter` into the “FIRST” column of the table. It is unclear why you would expect something else. From what I can decipher, it looks like you want to create all the columns FIRST, then, when adding the rows it may look something like… `dt.Rows.Add(WelcomeDrink, Starter,…);`. This is a guess as it is unclear from the code “what” you are trying to do.

Comment: @JohnG Thankyou so much for your comment and sorry for my bad code and lack of capability to convince my problem. I am a noob to coding. Please check this code too ,I have edited this code and now I have an output but the problem is now each column have a blank row before the displayed row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are neglecting to take into account how many rows you need in the table. Using your current approach where a new row is added for each checked box item in each check box list, then you end up such that only ONE item will be on each row. The first check box items will have their own row and so will each check box list. It may look something like…

---

```
Welcome Drinks       Starter       MainMeal      Desserts
Welcome Drinks 1
Welcome Drinks 2
                    Starter1
                    Starter3
                                    Main Meal 1
                                    Main Meal 4
                                                    Dessert 3
                                                    Dessert 4
```

---

Is what you need to do is check each `CheckedListBox` and figure out which check box list has the GREATEST number of items checked. This will tell you how many rows you need in the table. Then, instead of “adding” new rows in the `for` loops through each list, simply add the item to the existing row using the column name to determine which cell the value goes in.

To get the list check box with the greatest number of “checked” items may look something like…

```
int maxRows = chk1.CheckedItems.Count;
if (chk2.CheckedItems.Count > maxRows)
  maxRows = chk2.CheckedItems.Count;
if (chk3.CheckedItems.Count > maxRows)
  maxRows = chk3.CheckedItems.Count;
if (chk4.CheckedItems.Count > maxRows)
  maxRows = chk4.CheckedItems.Count;
```

Then add that number of rows to the table.

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxRows; i++) {
  dt.Rows.Add();
}
```

Now the table should have the proper number of columns and rows.

Since we know we have to loop through each `CheckedListBox` to get the “checked” items, it may help if we create a method that takes a `string` for the column name we want to put the values, the `CheckedListBox` and the `DataTable` and returns nothing.

This `AddColumnData` method, would loop through each of the “checked” items in the given `CheckedListBox` and add the items to the data table starting on the first row and the given column name. This method may look something like…

```
private void AddColumnData(string colName, CheckedListBox checkedListBox, DataTable dt) {
  int curRowIndex = 0;
  DataRow row;
  foreach (var checkedItem in checkedListBox.CheckedItems) {
    row = dt.Rows[curRowIndex++];
    row[colName] = checkedItem;
  }
}
```

With this method, it will make it easier to add the items to the table as shown below…

```
AddColumnData("WelcomeDrinks", chk1, dt);
AddColumnData("Starter", chk2, dt);
AddColumnData("MainMeals", chk3, dt);
AddColumnData("Desserts", chk4, dt);
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: That worked. How, you are this much good in coding ,I just keep looking into that codes for one  day and failed .How can I improve myself ?.

Comment: @ GOKUL RAJ … I am not _”much good in coding”_ … I may be more familiar with some aspect than you, however you will learn as time goes on. Keep learning and test things out… it will get easier. In this case, one thing that should have jumped out to you is how similar each of the four (4) `for` loops look. It is clear they are all doing the same thing just with different items. This should always be a red flag that a single method would be a better approach.

Comment: For beginners, one often overlooked aspect to coding is the debugging. You may code great, but if you don’t know how to find the problems, then it can be very difficult and you spend more time fixing errors than learning new things. Debugging is an art. Use the debugger, learn how to trace your code.

Comment: In the case for windows programming, debugging the UI can be challenging. Example, if you trace your current code and put a breakpoint on one of the lines… `dt.Rows.Add(row);` and step through your code, you will NOT see the added row in the grid. The UI will NOT update the grid automatically. So, while stepping through the code, you will not see this newly added row. Therefore, you need to look at the `DataTable` `dt` instead. Had you done this; you would have seen the problem right away. Point being, learn how to trace and debug your code, it will go a long way in making you a better coder.